# Installing vnstat on CentOS 6 shows "No package vnstat available"

Tags: centos, bandwidth

I'm trying to install vnstat on CentOS 6. I used the command found in the docs '`yum install vnstat`' but it shows the below:

```
[root@m2 ~]# yum install vnstat
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Setting up Install Process
    Determining fastest mirrors
     * base: mirror.its.dal.ca
     * extras: mirror.its.dal.ca
     * updates: mirror.its.dal.ca
    base                                                                                                    | 3.7 kB     00:00
    extras                                                                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
    extras/primary_db                                                                                       |  31 kB     00:00
    updates                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00
    updates/primary_db                                                                                      | 3.3 MB     00:03
    No package vnstat available.
    Error: Nothing to do
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the `No package vnstat available` issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vnstat` is not available in base repository. You first need to enable [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository with:

> yum install epel-release

After that, `yum install vnstat` should work.